# Web.config Url Rewrite Username (Php)

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, web-config, url-rewrite-module

How can I change the web rewrite url from (u/username) to (/username) like instagram.com/username

My web.config:

```
<rewrite>
<rules>
<rule name="Rule 1">
    <match url="^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)(|/)$" ignoreCase="false" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php?url={R:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>

<rule name="Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="u/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)(|/)$" ignoreCase="false" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.php?url=profile&amp;username={R:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
</rewrite>
```

I tried some rules before but I can't figure it out.

Comment: According to your description, I couldn’t understand your requirement clearly, which url do you want to rewrite to which url? please give an example, I will make demo for you.

Comment: So, my first Rule is for all the pages e.x (/home, /register etc) and my second Rule is for the users profile page which the url is "mySite.com/u/username". I want to make this to "mySite.com/username" without the "u" in the url just a username next to url like the pages from Rule one. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to rewrite `mySite.com/u/username` to `mySite.com/username`, you can refer to this rule:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
       <rule name="Remove u" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="u/(.*)" />
            <action type="Rewrite" url=mySite.com/{R:1} appendQueryString="false" />
       </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```